# Android MediaPlayer: Stream and write to file at same time.

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I'm trying to write to a media file, such as an MP3, and have MediaPlayer stream it from the file at the same time. Could this be done with FileDescriptors, or should I be using a local HTTP Server to serve the file as I get it?

Comment: Not sure if this helps but I have used a modified NanoHttpd (https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd) to successfully stream files to mediaplayer. So I vote for the Http solution :)

Comment: Looks reasonable. Just to be sure, you were able to use NanoHttpd similarly to what looks like the TempFilesServer in examples does, and stream those files to the MediaPlayer?

Comment: Basically yes, then I could "access" the file I wanted to stream locally via http://127.0.0.1/filename. It did need some small modifications though. Here's an example of NanoHttpd within an Android context: https://gist.github.com/komamitsu/1893396